# How to update working copy in Production after removing commit from repository

Tags: git

I have removed the last commit (`86f2cc...`) of a repository (Github) using this two commands on my local working copy:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git push origin +master
```

So after that, that last commit doesn't show up on Github commits list as expected.

THE PROBLEM:

After that, I have run `git pull origin master` on the working copy on the production environment and I get this:

[image]

It looks confusing to me that `(HEAD -> master)` and then on the next commit `(origin/master, origin/HEAD)`. I was just expected something like what I get on my local environment where the last commit just doesn't exist anymore:

[image]

So am I doing something wrong? should I run another command now? is just `git pull origin master` the correct command?

Comment: Check out the "Tip" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71444371/184546) for a possible alternative to `git pull` here.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't exactly done anything *wrong*.  You just haven't done the *right* thing yet.  What you need to remember is that *every Git repository has its own copy of all the commits*.

When you used:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

in your own (let's say "laptop") repository, that made the name `master` in your laptop repository select commit `897f1b2...` instead of selecting commit `86f2cc8...`.  The commit you "reset away" is not *gone*, it's just no longer the *most recent* commit on your own `master`.

When you used:

```
git push origin +master
```

you had your Git call up some other Git hosting site (at `origin`) and connect to a second Git repository over there.  *That* Git repository also has (it still has!) commits `86f2cc8...` and `897f1b2...` and *its* master selected the later of the two commits, but your `git push` commanded that other Git repository to set *its* master to the earlier of those two commits, and it obeyed this command, so now it, too, calls `897f1b2...` the latest `master` commit.

This deployment system has a *third* copy of the Git repository.  It has both of these two commits (as all Git repositories have all commits they have ever seen: Git is greedy for commits and holds on to them forever<sup>1</sup>) and *it* calls `86f2cc8...` the *latest* commit on *its* `master`.

When you ran:

```
git pull
```

on this system, *this* Git repository reached out to another Git repository—probably the one over on `origin`, to which you ran `git push --force` earlier—and asked it what its latest `master` commit was.  *That* Git said "my latest `master` commit is `897f1b2...`".  So this third system, with its third copy, said to itself: *Oh, I already have that.  And I have an ever later one!  I'll just update my memory of your Git's `master`, which I call `origin/master`, to say `897f1b2...`.*  Then it was time for this Git repository to add on any *new* commits it got from `origin`, but it did not *get* any new commits.  There was nothing to add on.  This third Git is *ahead* by one commit, and is ready to give this extra commit back to all other Git repositories that don't have it as the latest `master` commit.  So it just sat tight, smug in the knowledge that it's superior to all the other Git repositories.<sup>2</sup>

To "remove" the extra commit from `master` in this *third* copy, you must command *this* copy to move *its* `master` back one step.  You can do that with:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

if `master` is currently checked out here, or with:

```
git branch -f master master^
```

if `master` is *not* checked out here.  The later commit won't go away, but `master` in *this* Git will now have the second-to-last commit as its "last" commit.

**You must now also repeat this process in *every additional clone* that has the commit you want eliminated.**  This is why people don't *remove* commits: instead, we *add new commits* that *undo* the unwanted ones.  Git repositories are greedy for new commits and will add the new "undo" commit easily.  Git repositories are very reluctant to *remove* commits, and generally won't: you have to hand force *every Git everywhere* to give up that commit, before it can really go away.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, an *unreferenced* commit *can* go away, and on some servers it will go away relatively quickly.  Most Git repositories will stubbornly hang on to these commits for a minimum of 30 days, though, and often quite a bit longer.  For various GitHub-specific reasons, Git*Hub*'s Git repositories *never* give up *any* commit unless you get the GitHub folks to scrub it.

<sup>2</sup>The distributed nature of Git means that *every* Git repository is *always* superior to all other clones.

Comment: Every one of your answers is superior to all of your other answers.

Comment: @TTT: Peerless! 